# Windows, XAMPP, PHP 7 and opcache

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-7, opcache

I've installed latest XAMPP server with PHP 7 *(update: checked also PHP 7.1)* (on my *Windows 10* system). Wanted to use **opcache**, so I enabled it in `php.ini`.

```
[opcache]
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=0
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
```

With that change now, and with almost every page refresh, I'm getting this error from Apache:

```
AH00428: Parent: child process 3748 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
```

So, page is loading, and loading... waiting to Apache start again. When I'm turning opcache off (by setting `opcache.enable=0`), Apache is not restarting and everything works fine (omitting the slower web application topic, of course).

Everything works fine while loading app on XAMPP having PHP 5.6 with enabled `opcache`.

**EDIT (added GIF image):**
As you can see, sometimes page refreshes like it should. But sometimes it's refreshing much longer, and Apache is restarting in that moment.

[image]

**EDIT:**
To be honest, I gave up with this application and working with PHP on Windows (was working on it for around 10 years with PHP <= 5.6). It's very hard/impossible (for now) to make PHP 7.x work on that OS (with Opcache). Decided to go with **Ubuntu** and server created with **Docker**. Everything is easier to configure (especially with Docker) and works faster. I advise everyone to do the same ;).

Comment: Sounds like a bug in that module. I suggest you address the `xampp` project and create a bug report.

Comment: Have you restarted apache?

Comment: @JOUM Many times :D

Comment: did you try full path, like `zend_extension="G:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"`

Comment: @pinkalvansia In the 1st place :).

Answer (score 22):

Your `php_opcache.dll` **path seems wrong**, you need write it like below, it works for me.

```
[opcache]
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.max_accelerated_files=2000
```

### More details

If your XAMPP comes with PHP 5.5+ by default, opcache already included in the bundle, you will just need to enable it. To enable the extension:

1. Open php.ini (by default it should be located here: C:\xampp\php\php.ini).
2. Add this line at the end of the file:
   `zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll`
3. Restart Apache server.

Comment: Check for dll file  php_opcache.dll at this location: C:\xampp\php\ext\ and update your php.ini file with optimal configs and location of opcache dll file

Answer (score 6):

open a **php.ini** file

1. Change the **;opcache.enable=1** to **opcache.enable=1**
2. Add opcache dll path at the end of the file **zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"**
3. Restart apache

for more reference check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvWrNoRDjUY

Answer (score 2):

In case of Xampp, just put the below lines next to [opcache]

```
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest - do not use xammp. Right now we have a bit better tech stack, to run PHP on Linux servers. 
Docker
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

Vagrant:
https://www.vagrantup.com/

Both of them are based on linux systems, where most of xammp problems will not have place.

Answer (score 1):

### **First at all:**

This is 2022 and I had a similar problem too with PHP-7.2, not on Xamp, but similar server.

### **How I've got my problem solved?**

If you're here because of that, at first try to go with a default "opcache configuration options". And just above `opcache.enable=1` put `zend_extension=opcache`. Your PHP is smart enough to find the extension. And yeah, there's no need to define the full path if you have defined it here `extension_dir = [YOUR PATH]` (in php.ini). Of course you can use the full path too, if you want too. The path, probably, it's not a problem if your extension is there (in the folder with all PHP extensions). Did you checked, is it there, your extension?

My problem was in this two options:

```
opcache.memory_consumption
opcache.interned_strings_buffer
```

I have no idea why, but I guess this two option should have some balance, because both of them is about memory usage.

**So, this had my Apache useless, because it didn't wanted to start**

```
opcache.memory_consumption = 64
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 32 ;this one BAD
```

**next one works fine!**

```
opcache.memory_consumption = 64
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
```

**this one is works fine too!**

```
opcache.memory_consumption = 128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 32
```

So, as I said, at first try to go with a default values of "opcache configuration options", and later do experiments.

### **How to check everything works on PHP?**

```
var_dump ( zend_version() );
var_dump ( extension_loaded("opcache") ); // bool(false) cuz it's ZEND
var_dump ( extension_loaded("Zend OPcache") ); // bool(true)

// Next one will give you a lot of data about current opcache usage,
// but of course, only if your extension is enabled.
print_r ( opcache_get_status() );
```

Default OPcache configuration options you can find here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

Creeating directory with appropriate permissions and setting it php.ini worked!

```
opcache.file_cache=d:\xampp\htdocs\opcache
```

Comment: Can you explain more on how you did proceed to help solve this question?

Comment: It didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ThreadStackSize 8388608
```

Helped me in the similar case. This is a httpd option.

Comment: Can you be more precise about why you think that solves the problem? Randomly changing configuration looks like hocuspocus to me

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html    >>>Apache httpd may crash when using some third-party modules which use a relatively large amount of autodata storage.

Answer (score 0):

on php.ini add more

```
zend_extension=opcache
```

remove comment

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=0
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000
```

restart apache