# Apache error "error AH00428: Parent: child process 11144 exited with status 255" with PHP 7

Tags: php, apache, php-7

I am running Wamp server 3.0.6 64 bits with Apache 2.4.23 - MySQL 5.7.14

When I use PHP 5.6.25 everything works fine, I have no problem.

But when I use PHP 7.0.10 I get following errors on Apache log when I stress a little the application (several PHP request running at the same time and requesting mysql database through PDO connection)

```
[Wed Jul 26 18:55:25.459433 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11352:tid 616] AH00428: Parent: child process 5560 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Wed Jul 26 18:55:25.613195 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 11352:tid 616] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 26 18:55:25.703752 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11352:tid 616] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/7.0.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 26 18:55:25.703752 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11352:tid 616] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:43:51
[Wed Jul 26 18:55:25.703752 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11352:tid 616] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
[Wed Jul 26 18:55:25.703752 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11352:tid 616] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 12680
[Wed Jul 26 18:55:27.304382 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 12680:tid 648] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 26 18:55:27.324432 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12680:tid 648] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

I saw some posts with similar error on stackoverflow, but no answer solve my problem and there is no mention of PHP version that would cause that error.

Did anyone meet / solve that problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you are exceding the value of `MaxConnectionsPerChild`. When a child process exceeds `MaxConnectionsPerChild` value, active requests in the exiting process have TimeOut seconds to finish before processing is aborted. More details in [MPM Apache module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_winnt.html)

Comment: The thing is that it is working well in PHP 5.6.25 but not in PHP 7.0.10. Moreover during my tests I just had like 10 connections

Comment: Try this solutionsh.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49487367/9540128
Helped for me in the similat case.

Answer (score 0):

I had some deprecated **php_value** settings defined in **httpd.conf** that weren't indicated anywhere. Removing deprecated configurations stopped httpd.exe from crashing.