# In Drupal Installation I got many errors, Anyone can help me to shortout?

Tags: drupal-8

I am very Beginner to Drupal, And Currently I want to install 8.7.7 Drupal Version in My 7.2.19 Php version Xampp but During installation I got first Warning like

> PHP OPCODE CACHING
>   Not enabled
>   PHP OPcode caching can improve your site's performance considerably. It is highly recommended to have OPcache installed on your server.

After that I added below code to Php.ini file

```
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
```

Then I got other Fatal Error like,

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Drupal\Component\Utility\OpCodeCache' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\orange\core\install.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\orange\core\install.php on line 37

Can Anyone help me to solve this problem?
Not working for me

```
zend_extension="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"
zend_extension=php_opcache.dll

opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=256
opcache.max_accelerated_files=2000
```

Comment: Your version of PHP should have native OPCache. What happens if you remove both of the `zend_extension` lines? (Perhaps add `opcache.save_comments=1` and `opcache.load_comments=1`.) Reference: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php-requirements#drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed the **enable** line before the zend stuff. Also, did you **restart** the web server? 
Try this

open a php.ini file

```
1   Change the ;opcache.enable=1 to opcache.enable=1

2   Add opcache dll path at the end of the file zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll"

3   Restart apache
```

Credits to :  [Windows, XAMPP, PHP 7 and opcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028599/windows-xampp-php-7-and-opcache)

**Update**:
Maybe it’s using another php.ini file. 1) Try this to reveal the loaded file -  use example 1 in link below.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php

2)
Then see if opcache extensions are loaded by printing the file itself:

Put *test.php* somewhere in in you website with following content

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have already tried this method in Php.ini file. But it didn't work for me.

Is there any other solutions?